# binding c++ class I'm not able to find the constructor

Tags: javascript, c++, bind, emscripten

I'm working on binding a simple c++ class into javascript. I'm doing this via Emscripten 2.0.17.

I bound hello_world.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class hello {
    
public:
    
    hello() { std::cout << "Hello world!!!\n"; }
    
};

#include <emscripten/bind.h>

namespace emcc = emscripten;

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(jshello) {
    emcc::class_<hello>("hello")
        .constructor<>();   
}
```

using this command from terminal `./emcc_path/emcc --bind hello_world.cpp -o world.html`

Then I created a main.js file like the following

```
var hw = require("/home/kubuntu/Desktop/c++/hello_world/hello_world.js");
var x = new hw.hello();    
x.delete();
```

I tried to run with node 15.14.0 using `node main.js`
I got the following error

```
/home/kubuntu/Desktop/c++/hello_world/hello_world.js:117
      throw ex;
      ^

TypeError: hw.hello is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kubuntu/Desktop/c++/hello_world/main.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Does anyone can solve say me what's worng? thanks in advance

Comment: There are some errors and inconsistencies in your code that will make fails your code. i will post an answer to better explain.

Comment: What should I better explain?

Comment: No i was refering to me, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Exposing a class with Emscripten

If you want to expose a C++ class with Emscripten you need these steps, write your C++ code:

```
// hello_world.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Hello {
    
public:
    
    Hello() { 
        std::cout << "Hello world!!!\n" << std::endl;
        }

    void saySomething() {
        std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
    }
    
};

#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(jshello) {
    class_<Hello>("Hello")
        .constructor<>()
        .function("saySomething", &Hello::saySomething);
}
```

#### Building with Emscripten

build the C++ code with Emscripten, assumed that you have run the `emsdk_env.sh` you need to run:

`emcc --bind hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.js`

Note that the output is `-o hello_world.js`.

#### Module in example code

Now with the new wasm ad js files, write your main.js to load the Module:

```js
// main.js

var Module = require("./hello_world.js");

Module.onRuntimeInitialized = async function(){
    // uncommentthe code below to output the Module in the console
    // console.log('Module loaded: ', Module);
    var instance = new Module.Hello(); // this will print "Hello world!!!""
    console.log(instance); // this will pint the class as an object "Hello{}""
    instance.saySomething(); // this will print "something"
}
```

we wrap the code into a onRuntimeInitizialized function, in this way we are sure that our code is ready.

#### Test the code!

At this point you can test the code:

`node main.js`

The output in the console will be:

```
node main.js
Hello world!!!

Hello {}
something
```

#### Example code

You can test the code in this repository https://github.com/kalwalt/Emscripten-sketches/tree/main/hello_world_class

Happy coding with Emscripten!

Answer (score 1):

You simply call the `hello` constructor like this:

```
var x = new hello();
```

Once you require the js-module, its contents won't be nested into the variable you assigned it to, but rather become top-level to the current scope.

Comment: I just tried but I got this error `home/kubuntu/Desktop/c++/hello_world/hello_world.js:117
      throw ex;
      ^`